# markitup editor display output as html, and strip tags

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, bbcode, markitup

im using this rte in bbcode format.

http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/

once the textarea is submitted i'm saving it with bbcode format.

but i need 2 things.

- how do i now display it as html?
- how can i display without the bbcode tags (i.e just text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Convert in javascript](http://ufku.com/personal/bbc2html),

[Convert in c#](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2661.htm),

[Convert in PHP](http://psoug.org/snippet/Convert-BBCode-Tags_35.htm)...

There are a lot of ways to convert BBCode. If you want to get rid of the BBCode, you'll have to use a regular expression removing all the [ ] blocks. Something like this'll do:

```
return preg_replace('|[[\/\!]*?[^\[\]]*?]|si','', $yourblockofbbcode);
```

([source](http://twelvestone.com/forum_thread/view/28916))